# What was the body of Kama made of?

Tags: shiva, death, rebirth, body, kamadeva

*Kāmadeva* is perhaps the only *deva* who was resurrected from the dead. Generally, resurrection of the dead occurs in the same body. But in the case of *Kāmadeva*, his original body was burnt down by *Bhagavāna Śiva*. The fact that he had to wait in order to resurrect indicates that he was unable to create a body of his own.  So how was his new body created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is discussed in detail in the *Tāntrika* text *Mahākālasaṁhitā*.

While the *Lalitopakhyāna* of *Brahmaṇḍapurāṇa* states that *Bhaṇḍāsura* was created out of the ashes of *Kāmadeva*, the 12th chapter of  *Guhyakālīkhaṇḍa* of *Mahākālasaṁhitā* states that the ashes of *Kāmadeva* were converted into camphor. In Hindu tradition, camphor is renowned as a mouth-freshner & aphrodisiac. Before the introduction of tobacco (main ingredient of paan masala) by the Portuguese from the Americas, camphor was the main ingredient in *tāmbula*. The same text states that the usage of camphor as a material of *ārātrika* was first done in the marriage of *Gaurī* & *Śaṅkara*.

On request of *devī Gaurī*, *Bhagavāna Śiva* resurrected *Kāmadeva* by the application of the *Mṛtasañjīvanī/Mṛtyuñjaya mantra* (of which he is the presiding deity) into a body composed of herbs, leaves & flowers. The chief ingredient was the *damanaka* shrub (*Artemisia indica*, *Artemisia nilagirica*, *Artemisia dubia* & *Artemisia pallens*) created out of the tears of *Kāmadeva*'s wife *Rati* which fell over her husband's ashes. The 14th chapter of *Guhyakālīkhaṇḍa* of *Mahākālasaṁhitā* then states

- the face was created out of lotus flowers
- the nose was created out of the *campaka* flowers (*Magnolia champaca*)
- the eyes were created out of blue water-lilies (*Nymphaea nouchali*)
- the forehead was created out of *mallikā* flowers (*Jasminum sambac*)
- the temples were created out of *yūthika* flowers (*Jasminum auriculatum*)
- the ears were created out of *karavīra* flowers (*Nerium oleander*)
- the jaws were created out of *pāṭalā* flowers (*Bignonia suaveolens*)
- the collar-bone was created out of *mādhavī* creeper (*Hiptage beghalensis*)
- the cheeks were created out of *śirīṣa* flowers (*Albizia lebbeck*)
- the nostrils were created out of *vakula* flowers (*Mimusops elengi*)
- the neck was created out of the *karṇikāra* flowers (*Pterospermum acerifolium*)
- the arms were created out of mango saplings
- the hair was created out of *kuruṇṭaka* flowers (*Barleria longifloria*)
- the shoulders were created out of *kāñcanāra* flowers (*Bauhinia variegata* var *candida*)
- the abdominal muscles were created out of *kunda* flowers (*Jasminum multiflorum*)
- the chest was created out of *aśoka* flowers (*Saraca asoca*)
- the abdomen was created out of *ketakī* flowers (*Pandanus odorifer*)
- the sides were created out of *Jatī* flowers (*Jasminum grandiflorum*)
- the groin was created out of *kiṁśuka* flowers (*Butea monosperma*)
- the thighs were created out of the *śatapatra* leaves (*Anethum graveolens*)
- the shanks were created out of *Javā* flowers (*Hibiscus rosa-sinensis*)
- All the other limbs were created out of flowers like *pārijāta* (*Nyctanthes arbor-tristis*), *maruvaka* (*Meyna laxiflora*/*Clerodendrum phlomidis*), *kadamba* (*Neolamarckia cadamba*) & *bandhujīva* (*Pentapetes phoenicea*)

Keeping his wives *Rati* & *Prīti* on his both sides, his friend *Vasanta* (the personification of spring) in front of him in an environment filled with the sound of cuckoos & the breeze bearing the fragrance of sandalwood, *Kāmadeva* was resurrected on *Caitra suklā trayodaśī*.

> इयं तिथिरनङ्गाख्या तव नाम्ना भविष्यति । त्वामस्यां येऽर्चयिष्यन्ति गन्धपुष्पादिविस्तरैः ।। नैवेद्यधूपदीपाद्यैर्गीतवाद्यदिनर्तनैः । अश्लीलवचनाक्षेपैर्मादकद्रव्यभोजनैः ।। योनिलिङ्गादिशब्दानां प्रलापैर्हास्यकारकैः । तत्तदाकारवचनैर्महोत्सवसमन्वितैः ।। त्वं वरानीप्सितान् दद्यास्तेषां मद्वचनात् स्मर ।

> Translation: O *Anañga* ! This *tithi* will be named after you. O *Smara* ! By my order, you will grant the desired wishes of those who shall worship you on this day with articles like fragrances, flowers, *naivedya*, incense, *pradīpa*s etc & observe a great (night-long) festival accompanied by application of slang words, consumption of intoxicants (which means only cannabis because alcohol-consumption is prohibited), lame talk evoking laughter through application of words related to female & male genitalia. [*Mahākālasaṁhitā*:*Guhyakālīkhaṇḍa*:14:34-37.01]

The person who refrains from worshipping *Kāmadeva* on that day is said to lose all *puṇya* acquired in the month of *Caitra*.